# Is there is an oposite tool to static initializer in Java

Tags: java

Static blocks are executed when class is loading even before the `public static void main` starts. Is there any possibility to run a certain code just before the program close?

Comment: Just as a note: static initializers are actually `static {...}` blocks which get executed when a class gets loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). It's not a language level construct in the way that static initializer blocks are, but I think it'll do what you want.

You should be careful with shutdown hooks though - see the documentation for various warnings around them.

Answer (score 1):

From [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):-

Just to add a point to Jon Skeets answers

> **A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but unstarted thread**. When
>   the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all
>   registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run
>   concurrently. When all the hooks have finished it will then run all
>   uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled.
>   Finally, the virtual machine will halt. Note that daemon threads will
>   continue to run during the shutdown sequence, as will non-daemon
>   threads if shutdown was initiated by invoking the exit method.
>
> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop
>   running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual
>   machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal
>   on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual
>   machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example,
>   corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access
>   nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee
>   can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.